# coldfusion/xml - obtain a value by xmlName, rather than by xmlchildren array position

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Given the following XML "thisXML":

[image]

I can obtain the product name via

```
<cfset vProduct = thisXML.xmlchildren[1].xmltext>
```

But, how do obtain a value by xmlName, rather than by xmlChildren array position, i.e. in pseudocode:

```
<cfset vProduct = thisXML.xmlchildren[xmlName='product'].xmltext>
```

Comment: Look into XPath and XMLSearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get to it with `thisXML.Product` - it worked for me.

--xmltest.xml

```
<table1>
    <product>KiaOra</product>
    <SubscriberCode>2232481600</SubscriberCode>
</table1>
```

--xmltest.cfm

```
<cfscript>
    // this is setup stuff
    f = FileRead(expandPath("xmltest.xml"));
    x = XmlParse(f);
    xDetail = XmlSearch(x,"/table1")[1]; // this gets the exact result your cfdump image has

    // here is the important part
    writeOutput(xDetail.product.xmlText);
</cfscript>
```

--output

```
KiaOra
```

You just have to realize that even though your XML prints out in the detail view, it still works like XML in the standard cfdump view.